# Content assist (Ctrl-Space) in does not work in Eclipse in Debian Gnome running in VMWare for Windows

Tags: eclipse, debian, vmware, gnome

The **Ctrl-Space** key combination is not captured by my Eclipse IDE running on my Debian VM.

I changed the content assist preference to Shift-Space and it works fine.

I am running Debian Wheezy 64-bit Gnome inside of a **VMWare virtual machine** on Windows 8 64-bit.

I have checked:

- Eclipse (Window > Preferences > General > Keys) and checked the entry.
- Gnome shortcuts (System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts) and ensured there is no Ctrl-Space registered to anything.
- VMWare Workstation 9 (Edit > Preferences > Hot Keys) and deselected Ctrl.

In fact, when I try to reassign content assist to Ctrl-Space in Eclipse, I cannot do it. Eclipse will detect the Ctrl but not the space.

Is there a way to find out if another program in Debian is consuming Ctrl-Space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current default virtual keyboard app for Gnome runs at startup and captures **Ctrl-Space**.

Steps to fix:

- **Right-click** the keyboard icon in the Gnome bar.
- Select **Configure > Global Config**.
- Change **Trigger Input Method** from Ctrl-Space.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible issue, ctrl-space is used by newer versions of windows to switch the keyboard into Chinese mode.  To fix this in windows 7 I right clicked on the keyboard in the language bar went to settings and deleted all languages except English.

If the language bar is not present goto control panel -> region and language -> keyboards and languages -> change keyboards

Comment: I believe that is Windows Key->Space, not Ctrl-Space. See "Switch input language and keyboard layout" here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts#keyboard-shortcuts=windows-8